# RuntimeError for activity specified on Android Manifest

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, android-manifest

I have this problem that just seems strange.
I have this Android View with six buttons and when i click on one of them(the only one with the action defined apart from the exit button), it gives me a RuntimeError.
The Activity is declared on the manifest, and this is why i don't understand my error.
Can someone please help me with this.
I would really appreciate it :)

So here's my code:

```
package com.example.calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    View createButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
    View deleteButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    View moveButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_move);
    View searchButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
    View translateButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_translate);
    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit);
    createButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    moveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    translateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_create:
    Intent i = new Intent(this, CreateAppointment.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;
    case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        break;

    }

}

}
```

My layout is like this:

```
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="225dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

            <CalendarView
                android:id="@+id/calendar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_create"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/create" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_viewEdit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/viewEdit" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_delete"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/delete" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_move"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/move" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_search"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/search" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_translate"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/translate" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/exit"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.calendar"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.calendar.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CreateAppointment"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:label="@string/create" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you add the stacktrace with your question?

Comment: stacktrace? Pardon me for my ignorance, but what is stacktrace? @ZouZou

Comment: In the logcat, you said that you had a RuntimeError. Could you post the full log of this error please?

Comment: Code looks good from a quick scan through, need you stacktrace I guess. If you can't find your LogCat (and are using Eclise) go to Window -> Show View -> LogCat.

Comment: com.example.calendar                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)

Comment: Look through your LogCat for a part that says "Caused by....." and usually you can follow that to the line in your code that is popping the error.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.TextView  wich is makes it even more strange, since I'm not using any textviews

Comment: Oh, found it!! It wasn't the main layout giving me the error, but the other layout instead. I spelled Textview instead of TextView. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define correctly what kind of views ares using in onCreate()

```
 View createButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
```

for example:

since you are using a Button:

```
  <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_create"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/create" />
```

Make the cast as button:

```
 Button createButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
```

try this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button createButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
    Button deleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
    Button moveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_move);
    Button searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
    Button translateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_translate);
    Button exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);
    createButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    deleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    moveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    searchButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    translateButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Comment: thank you for the extra input. Will change it right now. However, I could find the error in the meantime :)

Comment: `View createButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_create);` is perfectly fine  (while not commonly used) if you only need the methods in the `View` class